# Is it possible to convert a euro Yaesu 991a to US band plan?

Tags: vhf, uhf, yaesu, europe, modification

I bought a euro Yaesu 991a . The vhf/uhf band plan is severely limited for use in the US . I have tried the button presses as shown for the earlier 991 and the service mode works to open the frequency for transmission but setting offsets etc are not possible . There must be a permanent fix because service mode shows than the unit can actually
transmit on the US band plan. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hello Rocco, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Hello Rocco, I added [tag:europe] and [tag:modification] to your question, to increase the likelihood of a good answer. Hope you don't mind. :-)

Comment: Rocco, if an answer works for you, please click on the "check" mark next to the answer. This will remove the question from the "unanswered" list to improve house-keeping. If an answer **does not** work for you, please let us know so we can remove incorrect information.

Answer (score 1):

This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNUnyZxu918) says that pressing FAST + A/B + A+B during power-on puts the radio into Service Mode, allowing you to extend the transmit frequency range. You must follow the steps indicated in the video precisely; in particular, you must set the radio's transmit frequency to the range on which you want to transmit before putting the radio in Service Mode.